# Kubuntu 14.04 ignores /etc/default/locale

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, locale

I run Kubuntu 14.04 and in the "System Settings/Locale" I always set "Country: Germany" and "Preferred language: American English".

For the command line, I set

```
#/etc/default/locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en"
LC_ALL="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

and that always worked out fine:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Now on the latest clean install, the GUI is fine but KDE overrides the command line settinges with the nonsensical

```
$ locale
LANG=en_DE.UTF-8
```

and if I change to "Country: France", it will change to "en_FR.UTF-8".

Futile efforts already tried:

- `locale-gen`: All sane locales are up-to-date
- `dpkg-reconfigure locales`: Changes nothing

Comment: Looks like [bug #1322968](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1322968).

Answer (score 1):

Delete `~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh`

Comment: Did that fix the issue without side effects?

Comment: I checked other machines I set up sometime and I must have deleted the script there too. I might add that this "fix" is only for those who choose to manage `/etc/default/locale` themselves (manually, via Puppet, etc.).